# Excel conditional formatting false hits

Tags: excel, list, search, formatting, conditional-statements

I am running search queries on bodies of text within Excel, but keep getting lots of false positives. For example, if one of my search terms is 'ton' then I am getting 'ton' 'wanton' 'Tony' etc. I really only want to format the cell when the original term appears as a whole word. I have Googled till I'm blue in the face, without luck...

If my search terms list is in column E, cells 2 to 32, then the formula I am using is as follows-

```
=MAX(INDEX(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$E$2:$E$32&"*"),0))
```

How can I amend this to include only whole words?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Those stars before and after, they are asterix for "any", yes?

So if you need to count only matches which are exactly "ton" then leave the stars out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. That makes sense, but I've tried it and it doesn't highlight the cells at all.